# Unable to get result of asynchronous call in the controller $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise, angular-resource

I was trying to improve the code in my application by moving the RESTful call in my angularJS to a factory like so:

In app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);
```

In services.js

```
swof.factory('engineerService', function($resource)
{
    var data = $resource('/api/engineers/:empid',{empid: "@empid"},
          {
          'get':
          { method:'GET'},
          'save':
          {method:'POST'},
          'query':
          {method:'GET',
          transformResponse: function(data)
          {
            return angular.fromJson(data);
          },
          isArray:true},
          'remove':
          {method:'DELETE'},
          'delete':
          {method:'DELETE'}
        });
   return data;
 });
```

In controller.js

```
engineerService.query().$promise.then(function(data)
{
  $scope.engineers = data;
  typeof $scope.engineers;
  console.log("[in]", $scope.engineers);
  $scope.$apply;
});
console.log("[out]", $scope.engineers);
```

The controller is referenced in the engineer.html page and the idea is that it will display a list of engineers from $scope.engineer.

The output in the Chrome console is as follows:

[image: Output in Chrome console]

For some reason I am unable to get the data returned from the REST query to appear outside of the section of the controller with the $promise.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: thanks for highlighting this to me. the information in the related question is useful but does not solve my problem since its not exactly the same, namely - I am using $resource and the solution proposed by setting the variable to false initially does not work in the scenario i have described. can you please reconsider your assessment? i really do need help to solve this problem.

Comment: Please try this and comment:
var data : any;
$scope.engineer = engineerS ... ponse)
    {
        data=response;
        return data;
    });

Comment: ok; trying now.

Comment: ok; i tried. set var data = "" and did a console.out($scope.engineer) after the  main block. it gives me a promise ( f { $$state .... } ). Is this what is to be expected? I'm trying to see the size of the array and elements now.

Comment: it seems to be the same as before.

Comment: i not have permissions for create chat rooms :(

Comment: I've revised my question based on the feedback received. My problem now relates to how I "get" the values returned from inside the section of code with $promise to be visible in the 'main' part of the controller.

Comment: i will check now and see. thank you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. First of all the services part:

```
swof.factory('engineerService', function($resource)
{
var data = $resource('/api/engineers/:empid',{empid: "@empid"},
        {
          'get':
          { method:'GET'},
          'save':
          {method:'POST'},
          'query':
          {method:'GET',
          transformResponse: function(data)
          {
            return angular.fromJson(data);
          },
          isArray:true},
          'remove':
          {method:'DELETE'},
          'delete':
          {method:'DELETE'}
        });
        return data;
});
```

Now for the controller:

```
swof.controller('engineerController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http', 'engSchedService', 'engineerService', function($scope, $log, $http, engSchedService, engineerService ) {

engineerService.query().$promise.then(function(data)
{
  $scope.engineers = data;
});
}]);
```

The values in $scope.engineers was accessed in html using ngrepeat as follows:

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="engineer in (filtered = (engineers | filter: query | filter: searchKeyword | orderBy: orderByField:reverseSort))">
```

Big thanks to everyone who contributed to help me with this. G